# Checking for existence of constants before defining them

Tags: constants

I am seeing many plugins use the following format for defining their constant:

```
/* Set the constant path to the plugin's javascript directory. */
if( !defined( 'MY_ETS_JS' ) )
    define( 'MY_ETS_JS', MY_ETS_URI . trailingslashit( 'js' ), true );
```

So basically there is a check before we define the constant.

My question is why is this check necessary? What if I make a new version of the plugin and want to change the name of the javascript folder from 'js' to 'javascript'? I would have to include that change in an upgrade routine. Why not just define the constants without checking for their existence?

Comment: Defined is used to check  whether a given named constant exists and not global variable. http://php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php

Comment: you would use `isset`, but this is basic PHP, not WordPress, read up on php.net and ask on stackoverflow if it continues to give you problems

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are not [PHP global variables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php), they are constants that cannot be modified(hence the name).

Trying to redefine them, using a [`define()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) will trigger a notice since they are already defined(and consequently keep the initial value assigned). To stay away from notices, you should check if they have been [`defined()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php) before.

Example:

```
define('VARIABLE', 'hello');
define('VARIABLE', 'world');
echo VARIABLE;
```

Results:

```
Notice: Constant VARIABLE already defined in **your-file** on line xxx
hello
```

In this case the variable won't be updated to `world`.

Example using `defined()`:

```
define('VARIABLE', 'hello');

if(!defined('VARIABLE')){
  define('VARIABLE', 'world');
}
else{
  echo "VARIABLE HAS ALREADY BEEN DEFINED.<br />";
}
echo VARIABLE;
```

Results:

```
VARIABLE HAS ALREADY BEEN DEFINED.
hello
```

In this case you can specify an action to perform in case that constant has already been defined.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot re-define defines. They're called *constants*. So this is more a check to not produce an error.

You either have to set a new define, or use a define, that in turn uses some dynamical part (i.e., a variable).